# How is it possible that Christians can go to heaven when they believe that Jesus is God

Tags: christianity

The Quran states:

"Those who believe, and those who are Jewish, and the Christians, and the Sabeans—any who believe in God and the Last Day, and act righteously—will have their reward with their Lord; they have nothing to fear, nor will they grieve."

This would imply that believing Jesus is God is fine. But since the Quran states that Jesus is not God, how is this different then believing Moses is God or Adam is God? In other words, if someone believes Moses is God instead of Jesus, but otherwise believes and behaves as would a Christian, can they still go to heaven?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the verse, read my linked answer especially the last half which explains this verse. And the Quran very explicitly says that the Christians have disbelieved and would be in hell fire: [5:72](https://quran.com/5/72?translations=20): *They have certainly disbelieved who say, "Allah is the Messiah, the son of Mary"  ... Indeed, he who associates others with Allah - Allah has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire.*

Comment: Thank you that clears it up